# $-\cos(\pi/3) = \cos(2\pi/3)$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove that:
$$-\cos(\pi/3) = \cos(2\pi/3),$$
using trigonometric identities.

Comment: This is incorrect, so of course you cannot prove it. Perhaps you copied it wrong.

Comment: how about now...

Comment: What identities are you allowed to work with?  I could say $\cos x = -\cos (\pi-x).$  But if that is not one of your Identities, I can't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Surely the OP will allow $\cos(\pi - x) = -\cos x$.  Or maybe prove it:

$$
\cos(\pi - x) = \cos(\pi)\cos(x)+\sin(\pi)\sin(x)
=(-1)\cos(x)+(0)\sin(x) = -\cos(x).
$$

Answer (score 2):

In general, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$\cos(\pi -x)=-\cos(x).$$
You can see this with help of the trigonometric circle.

Answer (score 0):

$-cos(\frac{π}{3}) = cos(\frac{2π}{3})$

Therefore, using the double angle formula you can figure out that:

$cos^2(a)-sin^2(a)+cos(a)=0$

And we know $a = \frac{π}{3}$
so we replace and we see that this identity is true.
$0=0$